# Why is my imported data getting messed up in mysql?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, import

I have a lot of scripts that are importing data from excel or csv.  99% of them are going fine.

I have one particular field - keywords - that is getting screwed up on import.

Example:

What I input for field--
>

> Accelus, GRC, Regulatory Intelligence, Policy Management, Relationship
>   Risk, Training, Audit, Risk Management, Compliance Management, Accelus
>   Compliance Manager, ACM, Accelus Risk Manager, ARM, Policy Manager,
>   World-Check, Country-Check, IntegraScreen, Audit
>   Manager,AutoAudit,eLearning,GRC00971

What I get for field--

> Accelus, GRC, Regulatory Intelligence, Policy Management, Relationship
>   Risk, Training, Audit, Risk Management, Compliance Management, Accelus
>   Compliance Manager, ACM, Accelus Risk Manager, ARM, Policy Manager,
>   World-Check, Country-Check, IntegraScreen, Au盻Ỵ盼

MySQL table is InnoDB/UTF8.  I have tried to use varchar and text for field but exact same results.  The file is being generated from a server that's database is UTF8 (supposedly).  Any suggestions - this is happening to quite a few rows and is killing export and lookup scripts for end users on our reporting site.

**UPDATE:**  I put the characters into google and they are Japanese (correct me if I am wrong).  So then I thought, let's open excel and see what happens.  Well the data looks normal but then when I change the column formatting to 'text' in Excel I see nothing but ##################### for the bad rows (just for that column)- note there are only a few out of the 7500.  All of the data before and after these rows and the rest of the "bad" row is all good.  It is just the one column.  So I guess I am dealing with an encoding issue but the letters look normal to me.

Comment: How does your `IMPORT` statement look like? Is there a line break in your csv right after 'Audit' in 'Audit Manager' or is it just here in your post? What do you mean with 'screwed up'? Wrong character encoding and / or anything else?

Comment: @mind-404 - I use navicat.  This particular table has 7500 lines and only an issue on like 5 of them.  Import just keeps going afterwards, so the next line is fine.  I should also say the next field is fine too on the same row.

Comment: Is it the last column per row that crashes? So, I might be related to the maximum row size. Which MySQL version are you running? `select version();`

Comment: @mind-404 - see my update.  I have mysql 5.5.  Would a row size issue kill just one field and then the rest of the row is fine?

Comment: Good question. But at least it should result in an error. Are there any errors / warnings logged? And apart from the fact that 'Audit' is encoded incorrectly, is the rest of the column truncated? Or is it only in your posting?

Comment: I suggest to `INSERT` only one of the erroneous columns into an empty row for testing purposes.

Comment: @mind-404 - This appears to be an issue with excel limiting the characters and maybe messing up csv too since it is default csv on server.  Still no fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Excel you cannot save csv files as utf-8**. It encodes CSV files using ANSI.

You can do the following:

> **1)** Choose "Save As"
>   **2)** in the "Save as type:" field, select "Unicode
>   Text". You'll get a Unicode file. (UCS-2 Little Endian)
>   **3)** Use Notepad++, Encoding menu / Convert to UTF-8 without BOM.

Another approach is to **covert the xslx to xls before the actual csv coversion**:

The lost characters / truncation issue seems to happen only when saving from xlsx format to csv format. Try saving the xlsx file to xls first, then to csv. The resulting csv is still not utf-8 encoded, but can be converted easily using a text editor like notepad++.

[Link to Excel Specifications](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx).

Comment: This is correct.  No idea why the Japanese characters were added - very confusing when some of our publishers are in Japan.  So first reaction was encoding.  Then trying to save as csv doesn't work as you noted.  Notepad++ works and also saving as a text/tab delimited in excel works.   The excel specs says each cell has a max 255 characters which is ambiguous because I have displayed 1000s of characters in cell but I guess you can't transfer them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the codification in PHP with

```
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

on top of the document

Comment: There is no php involved.  I am getting csv or excel with right data and when I do my import ... boom  get bad data at the end of the strings.